# Convert calendar date to julian date with a base date

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have calendar date (2021-08-18 10:00:00) I would like to convert it to julian date with basedate is (2021-01-01 00:00:00). The expected output is 229.4166

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can compute it from [`total_seconds()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.total_seconds.html):

```
t = pd.to_datetime('2021-08-18 10:00:00')
base = pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01 00:00:00')
(t - base).total_seconds() / (24 * 60 * 60)

# 229.41666666666666
```

Or if you have a Series of times, use [`dt.total_seconds()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```py
ts = pd.date_range('2021-08-15 10:00:00', '2021-08-18 10:00:00').to_series()
ts.sub(base).dt.total_seconds().div(24 * 60 * 60)

# 2021-08-15 10:00:00    226.416667
# 2021-08-16 10:00:00    227.416667
# 2021-08-17 10:00:00    228.416667
# 2021-08-18 10:00:00    229.416667
# Freq: D, dtype: float64
```